# Rate of Change of Cylindrical Roll's Volume as it Unrolls

Tags: calculus, geometry, algebra-precalculus

This is purely a "for-fun" question. I was minding my own business in the washroom this morning when I began to unroll some toilet paper from the roll, and in typical Breaking Bad fashion (sorry if you don't understand the reference) I had a serious moment where I wondered how the rate of change of the volume of the roll of paper changes as it is unrolled. Obviously the circumference of the cylinder keeps decreasing and as a result the ROC changes as well. I thought about it a bit but got stumped when I started writing things out (my math skills are a bit rusty).

I believe the beginning part of this solution [Accounting for changing radius of a paper roll to always unroll the same amount of paper](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/370909/accounting-for-changing-radius-of-a-paper-roll-to-always-unroll-the-same-amount) is the correct starting point for this question.
For simplicity, assume that the paper is rolled onto itself - no cardboard piece in the centre and the innermost layer's circumference approaches 0.
Also, assume that the roll is being unravelled at 1 circumference per second ($2\Pi r$/s) of the **outermost** (initial) layer.
Lastly, assume that there are 100 layers (100 circles as defined in the mentioned question) and each is 1 *unit-of-your-liking*.
Feel free to adjust any of these parameters to your liking!

Comment: Isn't the rate of change of _volume_ constant because you are removing the same number of squares (and hence removing the same volume) every second?

Comment: @Trevor: You aren’t. The rate of removal in squares per second is proportional to the circumference and hence to the radius.

Comment: @Brian Oh, I see, the angular velocity of the roll is constant rather than the linear velocity of the paper begin constant.  This is not how most people use toilet paper in real life, so I'll let my incorrect comment stand in case someone else makes the same mistake.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the roll is rotating at a constant angular rate, you will remove one layer per second all the way down.  As you started with $100$ layers, it will take $100$ seconds to unroll.  The remaining volume is proportional to the square of the remaining time.  If the starting volume is $V$, at time $t$ (seconds) there is $V\frac {(100-t)^2}{100^2}$ of the initial volume remaining.

Added:  if you want the paper removed at a constant rate, the angular velocity goes up as $\frac 1r$.  This is because the linear velocity is constant and $v=r\omega$.  Then we have $\frac {dr}{dt}=-k\frac 1r, \frac 12r^2=C-kt, r=\sqrt{2(C-kt)}$.  With $r(0)=r_0, r(100)=0$ we have $C-100k=0, C=\frac 12r_0^2,\\ r=r_0\sqrt{1-\frac t{100}}$

Comment: I guess I wasn't clear in my question. Imagine you are holding the end of the roll and walk away from it at a constant rate. The first layer will be removed in one second but subsequent layers will be removed quicker because the perimeter of each layer decreases whereas you keep walking at a constant rate.

Answer (score 0):

Let the Initial radius be $R$
Let the Radius at time $t$ be $r_t$ [$r_t$ is a function of $t$]

At time $t$ let the angular displacement be $\theta$ then the Volume that is reduced in $dt$ is:$$r_t*d\theta*{R\over 100}*h$$
That is:
$${dV\over dt }=r_t*d\theta*{R\over 100}*h$$
This should now be solved by a Double integral over $t$ and $\theta$.

Where:
${R\over 100}$ is the thickness of the roll.
${h}$ is the height of the roll.

Comment: Wow, it really is that simple eh? Can you think of anything pertaining to this question that would be more difficult to solve? Or there is simply nothing complicated about a cylinder...

Comment: Yes now i am also thinking this can be wrong,anyone can correct please?